# WebUI to explore AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 bucket to centralize my data. I don't want that my customer access it directly so I want to create a webUI to access S3 (a standard file explorer). The perfect example is the aws S3 console (on the administration) that can perfectly fit my needs : a basic online file explorer.

Unfortunately, I searched on google / github for a S3 file explorer projects but I was not able to find a good one.I also searched for a good standard file explorer where I can customize the controller to fit S3 methods.

Do you have any advice for me ?

Regards,
Romain.

Comment: Why don't you give read only access to your s3 bucket only to your customers?

Comment: Hi, we want to abstract the using of S3.